# Selenium Issue When Having tabular data in the form of DIV on a website where inside a DIV I have one div for every row

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, selenium

While writing Selenium automation test for a website having number of rows in the form of DIV  inside one DIV. every row denotes one DIV. suppose dynamically if I have 5 rows then following code structure is there.

```
<div id="mainDiv">
<div id-"div1"><table>......</table></div>
<div id-"div2"><table>......</table></div>
<div id-"div3"><table>......</table></div>
<div id-"div4"><table>......</table></div>
<div id-"div5"><table>......</table></div>
</div>
```

I am fetching each row div/table/tr/td using XPath in  for loop in my code and clicking on each. So that I can download pdf.
But it is working fine for 19 DIV. for 20th DIV I am not able to find that in my page using XPATH. I am getting no such element exception. though I applied wait then I get that explicit condition failed issue.
Can anyone having idea that its a scroll issue or anything else because of which I am not able to fine 20th and further more divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it looks like that element is not in **Selenium viewPort.**

You have *multiple ways* to deal with this :

**1. Scrolling :**

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)");
```

This is not very optimal way. Now, You can try for each element scroll to view :

**2.  scrollIntoView :**

Let's say you have a list of web elements. `(allDivs)`

```
for (WebElement div : allDivs){
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", div);
// and the do click or whatever
}
```

**3.**  **Use of moveToElement**

```
for(WebElement divs : allDivs) {
            new Actions(driver).moveToElement(divs).build().perform();
            // click on div here
        }
```

Comment: I tried moveToElement() and scrollBy. I used scrollIntoView() whithout this true parameter. I try with true. thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Is the url public ?

Comment: Can you share all the divs in any public domain ? Text format is appreciated.

Comment: I can not copy that outside. actually dynamically I am creating XPATH in for loop for accessing each element. the dynamix xpath is: //div[@id="gridx"]/div[2]/div[3]/div["+i+"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2] where i is the number of row. when I check in inspect I  can find upto div[@id="gridx"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[12]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]  afte 12th I am not able to see for 13th onward. though it is clicking till 19th row and for 2othrow it gets failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
This issue is solved now. earlier I was finding an element using Xpath with Div like //div[@id="gridx"]/div[2]/div[3]/div["+i+"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]. 

I found element using xpath with //*[contains(@rowid,"+i+")] because DIV has one attribute rowid for all rows.

But then I faced scroll issue. for that I used action.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).build().perform();
```